# NSOpenGLPFAColorFloat broken in macOS 10.12 (Sierra) for wide gamut (30-bit) rendering?

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl, core-animation, macos-sierra

It appears that something broke in macOS 10.12 when passing `NSOpenGLPFAColorFloat` as one of the parameters when creating an `NSOpenGLPixelFormat`. We're basically trying to follow Apple's [Deep Image Display with OpenGL](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/DeepImageDisplayWithOpenGL/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code in order to display wide gamut images on displays that support 30-bit color (10-bits for each RGB color channel).

This involves creating an `NSOpenGLPixelFormat` with an `NSOpenGLPFAColorSize` set to 64 (i.e. 64-bits per RGBA pixel) and `NSOpenGLPFAColorFloat` enabled (i.e. 16-bit half float sub-pixels). You then use that pixel format to create an `NSOpenGLContext` that uses 16-bit half float values for each sub-pixel, i.e. 64-bits for each RGBA pixel.

This was all working in macOS 10.11. However, under 10.12 our entire OpenGL window is rendered faded, as if it's being blended with a grey or white frame. Here's what this looks like - note that the window's title bar is properly rendered dark grey, but everything below that (our OpenGL view) is faded:

**10.12 (Faded)**

[image: 10.12 (Faded)]

**10.11 (Correct)**

[image]

I have verified that our OpenGL rendering is correct. If I use `glReadPixels()` to read the contents of the frame buffer after rendering then the contents of the frame buffer are correct - the contents are not faded and they do contain the proper "deep" (greater than 8-bits per sub-pixel) color data. The faded rendering appears to be happening somewhere outside of our app, possibly by the window compositor or something. So either this is a macOS 10.12 bug or we're not doing something properly when setting up our NSWindow, NSView or CAOpenGLLayer.

Apple's [Deep Image Display with OpenGL](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/DeepImageDisplayWithOpenGL/Introduction/Intro.html) sample does appear to work properly on 10.12. However there are a few differences between how it works and how our app works. Our pixel format is slightly different:

```
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attrs[] = {
    NSOpenGLPFANoRecovery,
    NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, 64,
    NSOpenGLPFAColorFloat,
    NSOpenGLPFADepthSize, 16,
    NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,
    0
};
```

The main difference is that Apple's sample is using `NSOpenGLProfileVersion4_1Core` and we're using `NSOpenGLProfileVersionLegacy` (the default if no profile is specified). So it's possible that it works for 4.1 Core profiles but not for legacy (Pre-OpenGL 3.0) profiles.

The other difference is that Apple's sample is using a subclass of `NSOpenGLView` while we're using a subclass of `NSView` with a subclass of `CAOpenGLLayer` where we do the OpenGL rendering. I suspect the issue may be with `CAOpenGLLayer` but I don't really know.

There are various properties on `NSWindow`, `NSView`, and `CAOpenGLLayer` that you can set that relate to wide gamut/deep image display. But so far none of them have had any effect. Properties that I've tried so far:

- `NSWindow.depthLimit = NSWindowDepthSixtyfourBitRGB`
- `NSView.wantsExtendedDynamicRangeOpenGLSurface = YES`
- `CAOpenGLLayer.wantsExtendedDynamicRangeContent = YES`
- `CALayer.contentsFormat = kCAContentsFormatRGBA16Float`

I've pretty much tried everything that I can think of at this point. If anyone has any tips or suggestions I'd very much appreciate them.

Comment: My current codebase requires a core profile so I can't easily repro your setup right now, but one thing that does strike me a bit odd about your pixel format is the use of 16 bits for the depth buffer.  I'm wondering if you might have accidentally confused the color bit depth with the Z buffer depth, as a 16 bit Z buffer is considered ancient these days.  I realize this isn't related to color space handling at all, but it could be possible you're getting an odd pixel format back due to that.

Comment: @Falken, I can just comment out the `NSOpenGLPFADepthSize` line or set it to 32 instead of 16 and I get the same result. I've also tried using the same pixel format parameters as in Apple's [Deep Image Display with OpenGL](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/DeepImageDisplayWithOpenGL/Introduction/Intro.html) sample (minus using `NSOpenGLProfileVersion4_1Core`) and get the same result. The only parameter that seems to change the behavior is when `NSOpenGLPFAColorFloat` is enabled.

Comment: Ah ok, it was a shot in the dark anyway.  :)  Sorry I don't have any other ideas right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the `colorspace` of the `CAOpenGLLayer` and the window.

If they don't seem appropriate for wide gamut, try changing them. If the window's is good but the layer's is not, it's probably best to set the layer's to match the window's (i.e. `layer.colorspace = window.colorspace.CGColorSpace;`).

Or you could just try setting the layer's to `CGColorSpaceCreateWithName()` with name `kCGColorSpaceSRGB`, `kCGColorSpaceExtendedSRGB`, `kCGColorSpaceLinearSRGB`, `kCGColorSpaceExtendedLinearSRGB`, or `kCGColorSpaceDisplayP3` to see if any helps.

Comment: Interesting that this does actually work, but it worries me. The layer's colorspace is NULL by default which according to the docs: _... **If nil, no colormatching occurs.** If non-nil, the rendered content will be colormatched to the colorspace of the context containing this layer (typically the display's colorspace)._ We don't want color matching on the layer as we do the color matching ourselves. Setting the colorspace to match the window's means that there shouldn't be any color matching anyway, so hopefully that's moot. But this seems like a possible ColorSync bug?